# Textbox overlap when in mobile

Tags: html, css

I have these textboxes, 
[image]

looks fine in when the browser is maximized but in mobile or when you minized the below textbox overlap the above textbox.

I'm using the below syntax:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="mrQuestionText">
      <style>
        .mrNext {
          min-width: 15em
        }
      </style>
      <div class="mrInstruct"></div>
      <table class="mrQuestionTable" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="odd">
            <th class="mrGridCategoryText" id="Cell.0.0" style="width: 320px;">お客様用「IDコード」</th>
            <td id="Cell.1.0" style="width: 75%;"><input autocomplete="off" class="mrEdit" id="_Q1_Q0_Q0" maxlength="1024" name="_QQPage_QUserPage_QUser_Qslice" type="text" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="even">
            <th class="mrGridCategoryText" id="Cell.0.1" style="width: 320px;">お客様用「パスワード」</th>
            <td id="Cell.1.1" style="width: 75%;"><input autocomplete="off" class="mrEdit" id="_Q1_Q1_Q0" maxlength="1024" name="_QQPage_QUserPage_QPass_Qslice" type="password" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Apologies, as I can't share the full syntax.

Kindly advise if there is any property that i should add/update.

Comment: try putting padding on your td beforehand?

Comment: thanks for your suggestion guys. this is working fine now, i just added display: block property :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use padding on your td elements in the media query.
html

```
<table class="mrQuestionTable" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td class="mrGridCategoryText" id="Cell.0.0" style="width: 320px;">お客様用「IDコード」</td>
            <td id="Cell.1.0" style="width: 75%;"><input autocomplete="off" class="mrEdit" id="_Q1_Q0_Q0" maxlength="1024" name="_QQPage_QUserPage_QUser_Qslice" type="text" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="even">
            <td class="mrGridCategoryText" id="Cell.0.1" style="width: 320px;">お客様用「パスワード」</td>
            <td id="Cell.1.1" style="width: 75%;"><input autocomplete="off" class="mrEdit" id="_Q1_Q1_Q0" maxlength="1024" name="_QQPage_QUserPage_QPass_Qslice" type="password" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px){
    .mrQuestionTable tbody tr td {
      padding-bottom: 1em;
    }
}
```

Comment: still nothing happen :(

Comment: yes, thats what i did. I've updated it via .html. What i noticed is then the width of the page goes below 720px the textbox hide.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following for table

```
border-spacing: 5px (spacing u wish)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code, you were missing a semicolon here `min-width: 15em`. Also you need to restructure your code.

Since I am not able to reproduce the issue, I suggest you to use the below updated styles. I have used `border-spacing` below, try that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .mrNext {
      min-width: 15em;
    }
    
    .mrQuestionTable {
      border-collapse: separate;
    }
    .mrQuestionTable tr{
      border-spacing: 10px;
    }
    
    
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="mrQuestionText">
      <div class="mrInstruct"></div>
      <table class="mrQuestionTable" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="odd">
            <th class="mrGridCategoryText" id="Cell.0.0" style="width: 320px;">お客様用「IDコード」</th>
            <td id="Cell.1.0" style="width: 75%;"><input autocomplete="off" class="mrEdit" id="_Q1_Q0_Q0" maxlength="1024" name="_QQPage_QUserPage_QUser_Qslice" type="text" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="even">
            <th class="mrGridCategoryText" id="Cell.0.1" style="width: 320px;">お客様用「パスワード」</th>
            <td id="Cell.1.1" style="width: 75%;"><input autocomplete="off" class="mrEdit" id="_Q1_Q1_Q0" maxlength="1024" name="_QQPage_QUserPage_QPass_Qslice" type="password" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! but still the same issue.

Comment: Can you provide more information about device, browser? I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: The issue happen if the device has below 720px width resolution. I'm testing it via sourcecode(F12) in Google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You add `white-space: nowrap;` for 1st column
and `th` -must be only in the `thead` section

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="mrQuestionText">
      <style>
        .mrGridCategoryText{white-space: nowrap;}
        .mrNext {
          min-width: 15em;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="mrInstruct"></div>
      <table class="mrQuestionTable" role="presentation">
        <tbody>
          <tr class="odd">
            <td class="mrGridCategoryText" id="Cell.0.0" style="width: 320px;">お客様用「IDコード」</td>
            <td id="Cell.1.0" style="width: 75%;"><input autocomplete="off" class="mrEdit" id="_Q1_Q0_Q0" maxlength="1024" name="_QQPage_QUserPage_QUser_Qslice" type="text" value=""></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="even">
            <td class="mrGridCategoryText" id="Cell.0.1" style="width: 320px;">お客様用「パスワード」</td>
            <td id="Cell.1.1" style="width: 75%;"><input autocomplete="off" class="mrEdit" id="_Q1_Q1_Q0" maxlength="1024" name="_QQPage_QUserPage_QPass_Qslice" type="password" value=""></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```